# Do we need the "consecutive" term in this definition?

Tags: permutations, tensors, permutation-cycles

[image]
I tried to find an example in which "consecutive" make a difference, but I can't find it. For example here I have an odd number of exchanges regardless of whether I limit myself to consecutive or not:

[image]

And here I have an even number of exchanges independently I limit myself to consecutive interchanges or not:

[image]

Can you give me a counterexample in which there is a difference between making exchanges in general or making exchanges only between consecutive ones make a difference in odd/even steps we need to reach the final state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A such counterexample doesn't exists because the [parity of a permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) doesn't depends on the decomposition into product of transpositions (adjacent or not).
This means that, although such a decomposition is not unique, the parity of the number of transpositions in all decompositions is the same.

Consequently, we don't need the “consecutive” term in this definition.